# Mongo docker image - unable to run on different port

Tags: mongodb, docker

There are a tons of question here on SO citing how this command alone

```
docker run --name mymongo --network bridge -p 27117:27117 -v "$PWD/db":/data/db  -d mongo
```

should run mongo on port 27117. 
However this doesn't work for me. The container runs, but the mongo is run on its default port alone (see output from container itself):

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

# mongo --port 27117
MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27117/
2018-11-20T17:26:09.345+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27117, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27117 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
```

What is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it be fire wall issue?

Comment: i'm trying from within the docker container, so no firewall there (i think)

Answer (score 6):

Inside your container mongo runs on its default port, which is 27017

So, you should modify your command and specify the port mapping like this:  `-p 27117:27017`

The full command would be this:

```
docker run --name mymongo --network bridge -p 27117:27017 -v "$PWD/db":/data/db  -d mongo
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought the port:port was a range of ports to be opened, and not a port mapping :) always learn something!

Answer (score 2):

With that command you are telling docker that the port is 27117, but you also need to start mongo with that port.

To do so, just add `--port 27117` at the end of your command:

```
docker run --name mymongo --network bridge -p 27117:27117 -v "$PWD/db":/data/db  -d mongo --port 27117
```